# Getting HttpServletRequestWrapper in Jersey

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I wrote an HttpServletRequestWrapper named HTTPRequest that reads the full HTTP POST body for further use. This one is based in the code at http://natch3z.blogspot.com/2009/01/read-request-body-in-filter.html

My Jersey server application needs to get this wrapper to read the body. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that.

I've tried putting

```
@Context HTTPRequest request;
```

but it does not work (Missing dependency for field).

I've tried too doing:

```
@Context HttpServletRequest request;
```

then casting to HTTPRequest, it didn't work neither ($ProxyXXX cannot be cast to HTTPRequest).

I've searched for information in the Internet but I cannot find anything regarding this. Any idea? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand: `HTTPRequest` is your objects extending the HttpServletRequestWrapper, right?

So if you want Jersey to inject it via the @Context annotation, you need to implement the `ContextResolver`. Actually in your case it should be easy:

```
@Provider
HTTPRequestContextResolver implements ContextResolver<HTTPRequest> {

@Context HttpServletRequest request;

  HTTPRequest getContext(Class<?> type) {
      return new HTTPRequest(request);
  }
}
```

**Updated:** If you already wrapped the original request in a filter, you may have a problem to get it, since Jersey wraps the original request using the dynamic proxy.

Comment: Thank you so much. Anyway, I've solved it using another approach. The HttpServletRequestWrapper was on a filter. Additionally, a watch in the original request received by the wrapper existed. Thus, the debugger was reading the body to update the watch before me. Finally: the HttpServletRequestWrapper overloads the getInputStream() method with a cached copy of the POST body, so I can read this InputStream furtherly to get the POST body itself :)